# xdbprocessing role not starting. throwing error for requested document not found

Tags: processing

We set up `xdbprocessing` role on Sitecore 10.2 using SIF install on a new server. It's a scaled environment. We used `Sitecore-XP1-prc.json` to setup Sitecore `10.2.0 rev. 006766 (OnPrem)_prc.scwdp.zip`.

- certificates are correct
- xconnect service is working
- installation throws no error
- connectionstrings values are correct.

logs file is also not helping. please suggest how to ensure that this role is correctly set up.

after installation when we try to open the URL from IIS it throws an error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, as the processing instance doesnt have served content / front end.

If you are wanting to check it is up and running correctly, try this url:

```
https://<your-domain>/healthz/live
```

If all is well you should see: `Healthy`